# Unspecified Margin Problem?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On [this page](http://www.glamourunderground.com/the-ultimate-one-day-makeover/), the title says it has a margin top & bottom of 25px (when I use inspect element in Chrome 10) - but the CSS looks like this:

```
.post h2 {
margin:0;
text-align: left;
font-size: 18px;
overflow:hidden;
font-weight:normal;
}
```

I'm trying to decrease the top and bottom margins around the title.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:[image: Margin Problem]

Comment: Thanks @mingos. The link's actually correct. I think it must be my server?

Comment: Ok, looks like it's working now! @mingos & @anish - Sorry about that.

Comment: The title element is display none. I assume that by 'title' you mean 'some heading', but I can't tell which one. There is no element (as far as I can see) which is a member of the post class, so I don't know what elements that rule is supposed to apply to, and I'm not idea how the title is telling you what margins it has.

Comment: @david - on that page, when I right click the title of the article, just above the picture and then click Inspect Element, Chrome is telling me that it has 25px margin top & bottom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see there no problem in your `class=title`and your h2 have this:

```
h2 {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: HarabaraHandItalic;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

and

```
.title {
      background: url("images/title.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        padding: 0;
}
```

the url is not working and you can add margin in your h2 instead.

Comment: Thank you =) That was the problem. It works now. I just put margin:0; in the h2 {}

Answer (score 1):

There's no such element on the page. You should edit `.title h2` instead of `.post h2`.

Comment: Please see screen shot (I'll put it in original question now)

Comment: Yes, I understood that without the screenshot. What I have written is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

The `<h2>` is displaying a default margin (which varies depending on the browser); if you want to edit the margin, use `.title h2` or the generic `h2` (line 405 of style.css according to FireBug - this will alter all `<h2>`s on the site though).

Comment: This is my h2 CSS: `h2 {
 font-family: HarabaraHandItalic;
 font-size: 30px;
 padding: 0 0 0 15px;
 color:#000;
}`

And, there is no .title h2

Comment: @Tara in that case, just create it somewhere relevant in the CSS sheet and add a margin property. This will allow you to control the title h2 instead of all h2s on the site.